# Loading a SharePoint FAQ into Azure QnA maker

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-qna-maker

I have been trying to load a FAQ hosted on a Intranet SharePoint site but get an error (Bad Argument: [SharePoint address] - Unsupported / Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source when loaded into

Is it possible to load in a basic share point page with a list of questions and answers into an Azure QnA Maker knowledge base?

Any insight into this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately No! QnAMaker extracts only URLs which are publicly available, no intranet, no any kindof URL which needs authentication.

As a workaround, copy the question and Answer content and save it in .docx, pdf,.tsv or any other supported file format, and upload the same for creating knowledgebase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has answered you question and now you can add a sharepoint url from intranet to qnamaker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources